# is CSRF a threat in simple Hash Calculator PHP application?

Tags: php, security, hash, csrf

I am working on hash calculator coursework. This is simple web application which contains on the main page two submit forms where users allowed to submit hash and get text back and vise a verse.

Even though, the application is trivial, it requires to implement security features inside it. I managed to mitigate SQL and XSS attacks. Then, i decided to used two vulnerability assessment scanners "Acunetix" and "Nessus". Both scanners showed me that my application is vulnerable to CSRF and protection to this attack is to implement sessions and random tokens in PHP.

I have read about this attack and what it does. However, i got very confused due to the fact that this attack mainly focus on already authenticated users and cookies so my question is? Do i need to embed sessions and tokens to my application that simply return and recovers hash and plaintext?If yes, why i should do it and what potential threats around?

Thank you very much!

Comment: CSRF protection is really a way to make sure that any request comes from your form (so nobody can post to your back end from somewhere else). Without CSRF, anyone could use your back end with their own front end. So in reality, if you care about that, add CSRF. If you don't care if someone posts to your back end from their own site/script, then you don't need CSRF.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Anti-CSRF won't protect against MitM/proxies.

Comment: @user2864740 Of course not. There isn't just one protection that protects you from everything. But in an application like this, I think that man in the middle attacks really aren't a big threat.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson "Without CSRF, anyone could use your back end with their own front end." - Anti-CSRF won't address this (MitM/proxy), so that will still be possible.

Comment: See [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) for a good general read. The basic issue with CSRF is that it allows (due to users using the same browser with *preserved cookies and auth, etc.*) a crafted request - one that "calls unwanted operations" - to assume the current session-state (often this is for an account one is "logged into" although it affects all session-states). If there is no session-state then CSRF does not even apply.

Comment: Also note that CSRF is also strictly *operation/state based*, further making it likely non-applicable to two web calls that returning values based off of the input and *don't* perform state-change operations .. that said, I'm not sure how the code expects to "get back text from a hash" :}

Comment: @user2864740 I respectfully disagree, as detailed in my answer. While usually CSRF is indeed related to session state and/or state change, I show two CSRF scenarios in my answer that may apply here, because if for example the performed operation takes a long time or uses a large amount of resources, performing it is state change by itself.

Answer (score 2):

You are right in your question, CSRF protection needs to be a conscious decision. I think you may at least want to consider doing it in your application, and here is why.

CSRF is about another website being able to trick a user into inadvertently performing actions in your application while visiting the malicious one. True, most of the time this exploits the fact that the user is already logged in, but that is not necessarily the case.

For your application, the two CSRF-related threats that immediately come to mind are:

- Hashing is very CPU intensive, and also the other way, search operations in a large rainbow table can also be resource intensive. This by itself is already a denial of service risk, but you could counter that by for example filtering out source IPs with too many requests. However, if your app is vulnerable to CSRF, a high-traffic website can have it's visitors perform such operations in your app, effectively performing a distributed DoS, which is much harder to protect against.
- Very similarly, if you have an API for the app and no protection against CSRF (eg. you have access-control-allow-origin: *), any other website will be able to run as much queries as they want, either hash or search, which may lead to lost income or distributed denial of service).

Maybe these are not applicable to your exact use-case, I just wanted to note that even though there is no session state of any kind, CSRF can indeed be an issue, and the tool to systematically uncover such potential threats is called threat modeling.

Comment: CORS only applies to to browser XHR/intrapage resource requests. While this can mitigate a certain class of CSRF by "covering" those access, it does not look to solve CSRF. So, imagining that there is an "expensive GET operation", how does enabling CSRF prevent this?

Comment: @user2864740 I didn't mean to suggest that. I proposed two scenarios where CSRF can be an issue in this application without session state and state change in the traditional sense. GET operations are inherently vulnerable to CSRF, so you can't really implement proper CSRF protection with GET.

Comment: Then it's not CSRF.. :} I'm not against using additional better-practices for hardening applications (and bringing up CORS / DDoS are very valid points), but CSRF has a very narrow definition.

Comment: Yes, I just realized this, we are talking about the definition of CSRF. :) Thanks for your insight, it's useful for me at least. I defined CSRF above as "another website being able to trick a user into inadvertently performing actions in your application while visiting the malicious one". I think your definition is narrower than that, that's all. :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : no you don't, since you don't have 'users' ( authentication ) you don't need csrf token.

Comment: Any cookie-based session-state is susceptible to CSRF. In this case it sounds like there is no session-state. (While most "sensitive operations" are protected via authentication, authentication is not strictly a prerequisite.)

Comment: most of them time it is, but in this cause he doesn't need csrf protection

Comment: I agree with the conclusion in this case.

Comment: I disagree, in some cases CSRF can be an issue in stateless applications as well, see my answer.